# Openshift - gitlab-cli - phantomjs - WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start

Tags: selenium, phantomjs, gitlab-ci

I have a setup of a Java project with acceptance tests (i.e. concordion tests).
Locally with a chrome and phantomjs driver (on windows) the tests are passing (i.e. ran by gradle).

when running on gitlab-ci (with a runner in openshift), I get the following exception:

```
  java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at be.axians.actemium.milter.helper.BrowserTestParent.openBrowser(BrowserTestParent.java:32)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

    ...

    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'runner-5408090a-project-349-concurrent-0dtvl2', ip: '10.131.1.51', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.10.0-514.26.1.el7.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: driver.version: PhantomJSDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:193)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:181)
    at org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSCommandExecutor.execute(PhantomJSCommandExecutor.java:78)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:637)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:250)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:236)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:137)
    at org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver.<init>(PhantomJSDriver.java:116)
    at be.axians.actemium.milter.helper.WebDriverManager.<clinit>(WebDriverManager.java:53)
    ... 52 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker$TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for [http://localhost:7465/status] to be available after 20001 ms
    at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:107)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:190)
    ... 60 more
Caused by: com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedTimeoutException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(SimpleTimeLimiter.java:140)
    at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:80)
    ... 61 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:205)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(SimpleTimeLimiter.java:128)
    ... 62 more
```

The driver is initialized as follows:

```
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.phantomjs();
        capabilities.setJavascriptEnabled(true);

        PhantomJSDriverService service = new PhantomJSDriverService.Builder()
                .usingPhantomJSExecutable(new File("/actemium/milter/acceptance-tests/driver/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs"))
                .usingAnyFreePort()
                .build();
//
        driver = new PhantomJSDriver(service, capabilities);
```

with the given dependencies:

```
testCompile "com.codeborne:phantomjsdriver:1.4.3"
phantomjs-1.9.8
```

And with the following gitlab-ci config:

```
acceptance-test:
  stage: acceptance-test
  services:
   - jboss/keycloak:3.3.0.CR1
   - postgres:latest
  variables:
    POSTGRES_DB: "..."
    POSTGRES_USER: "..."
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "..."
    KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: "..."
    KEYCLOAK_USER: "..."
  script:
    - ls
    - cd acceptance-tests/driver
    - ls
    - tar xf phantomjs-1.9.8-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2
    - ls -al
    - mv phantomjs-1.9.8-linux-x86_64 phantomjs
    - ls
    - ls phantomjs
    #- ls -al phantomjs/bin
    #- ln -s phantomjs/bin/phantomjs /usr/bin/phantomjs
    - ls -al /actemium/milter/acceptance-tests/driver/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs
    - cd ../..
    - ls
    - pwd
    - ./gradlew -g .gradle_home acceptanceTest -Dspring.profiles.active=at --stacktrace
  artifacts:
    when: on_failure
    paths:
      - acceptance-tests/tests/build/reports/tests
    expire_in: 1 week
```

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

My solution for PhantomJS was installing a hidden dependency:

```
yum install -y libfontconfig1 fontconfig libfontconfig1-dev libfreetype6-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

You can perform all operations using headless via Chrome browser. Don't use HTMLUnit as it have many configuration issue.

PhantomJS was another approach for headless browser but PhantomJs is having bugs these days because of poor maintenance of it.

You can use chromedriver itself for headless jobs.

You just need to pass one option in chromedriver as below:-

```
chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless");
```

Full code will appear like this :-

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\Workspace\\JmeterWebdriverProject\\src\\lib\\chromedriver.exe");
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless");
chromeOptions.addArguments("--start-maximized");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/");
```

If still you want to use phantomjs.
Then first download the phantomjs binary from below URL :-

http://phantomjs.org/download.html

Complete code will be like below :-

```
System.setProperty("phantomjs.binary.path","D:\\Workspace\\kumolus-test-automation\\src\\lib\\phantomjs\\phantomjs.exe");
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = null;
ArrayList<String> cliArgsCap = new ArrayList<String>();
capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.phantomjs();
cliArgsCap.add("--web-security=false");
cliArgsCap.add("--ssl-protocol=any");
cliArgsCap.add("--ignore-ssl-errors=true");
capabilities.setCapability("takesScreenshot", true);
capabilities.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
capabilities.setCapability(
    PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_CLI_ARGS, cliArgsCap);
capabilities.setCapability(
    PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_GHOSTDRIVER_CLI_ARGS,
        new String[] { "--logLevel=2" });

WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver();
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/");
System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
```

Change the location of Phantomjs location path in above code's 1st line

Comment: I will try. My solution for PhantomJS was installing a hidden dependency: yum install -y libfontconfig1 fontconfig libfontconfig1-dev libfreetype6-dev. But prefer headless chrome if possible ;)